# Pandas df: How to skip over specific dates in dt indexed for-loop

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a df that's indexed by 1 minute resampled data. I'm currently trying over to iterate over 1 minute resampled dataframe such as shown below. I'm trying to make it so that the conditions inside checks if the index, which is a minute by minute data, checks if the date time is

i. between the last 2 days and first 2 days of the month
ii. if its between the month of july to nov
iii. if its between a certain hour of the day

I'm trying to analyse some minute phenomenon but I think the data is erratic for those 2 points above, so I would like to remove them or check for those conditions to let the algorithm ignore them. Thank you!

The index I'm iterating over is MINUTE by MINUTE data.

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
  if (not first 2 days of every month and not last 2 days of every month):
    #do something
  elif (not during july TO november):
    #do something
  elif (not between 8am and 9am):
    #do something
  elif (not all):
    #do something
```

So right now I'm doing

```
for index, row in df:
  if index not in pd.date_range('2018-08-01', '2018-09-01'):
    df['new_column'] = df['data']*2
```

But this doesn't seem to work for the df below.

```
                     data
Datetime    
2018-01-03 08:13:00 207.45
2018-01-03 08:14:00 207.45
2018-01-03 08:15:00 207.45
2018-01-03 08:16:00 207.45
2018-01-03 08:17:00 207.45
```

Comment: I think I vaguely understand the post, but you've not given us any data to work with as a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating three filter masks to avoid looping:

```
mask1 = (df.index.day > 2) & (df.index.day <= df.index.days_in_month-2)
mask2 = (df.index.month < 7) | (df.index.month > 11)
mask3 = ~df.index.indexer_between_time('08:00', '09:00')
```

then using them as:

```
df.assign(new_col1=np.nan, new_col2=np.nan, new_col3=np.nan)
df.loc[mask2, new_col2] = df.loc[mask2, 'data'] * 2
```

or

```
df.assign(new_col2 = mask2 * df.data)
```